# You like to have a drink after you kiss me - who am I?

Tags: riddle

> You like to have a drink after you kiss me
>   And if you've got the stomach for it, you can eat me
>   When I am last, I am not least
>   I'm said to overpower beasts
>   And though I'm weak and thin and frail
>   Don't argue with my man - you'll fail

**Who am I?**

Hint:

> Once more, who am I - can you guess?
>  Let's have a poll, it's only fair
>  In fact, I'm well within your grasp
>  Just when you feel close to despair

Comment: Is it normal/kosher in these kinds of puzzles to use the same *word* but with different meanings, different *things* being referred to, across the verses?

Comment: @JDługosz well, it's a common enough thing to do/see in a riddle. Whether it's kosher is a subjective question. It's perfectly okay if you believe riddles shouldn't do that, and you can use your votes and commenting abilities to try to push the Puzzling community in that direction.

Comment: @JDługosz on second thought, I think this device of playing on two different meanings of a word is actually extremely common in constructing riddles, and probably it would be quite difficult to construct a good riddle not using this technique. So yes, it's normal, and considered kosher by almost everyone as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> straw

You like to have a drink after you kiss me

> You put your mouth on a straw to take a drink

And if you've got the stomach for it, you can eat me

> You can (or at least, some animals can) eat straw

When I am last, I am not least

> The final straw, which is (according to the first google result) the "last in a series of unpleasant events which finally makes you feel that you cannot continue to accept a bad situation"

I'm said to overpower beasts

> The straw that broke the camel's back

And though I'm weak and thin and frail
Don't argue with my man - you'll fail

> A straw man argument is a fallacy where someone argues against a point that hasn't been made.  If you use a straw man argument, you fail.

Edit: And the hint...

Once more, who am I - can you guess?
Let's have a poll, it's only fair

> A reference to a [straw poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_poll).

In fact, I'm well within your grasp
Just when you feel close to despair

> A reference to "[grasping at straws](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grasping+at+straws)."

Comment: This is correct, and very nicely explained - great job! Before I officially accept the answer, would you care to address the hint?

Comment: Draw; grasping?

Comment: Straw poll (test vote), grasping, the last.

Comment: @dlu Oh, yeah, straw poll, that makes more sells. I guess draw straws would be "pull."

Comment: Now, how to work that into the hint?

Answer (score 9):

Can it be

> Chillies/peppers

1. > We need to drink water if while eating it touch our lips.
2. > It your stomach can take the chillies you can eat.
3. > not sure
4. > not sure
5. > chillies are thin and can be broken into two pieces easily
6. > Men are being referred to as the seeds we see inside the chillies

Comment: Please explain why a downvote ? It's just a try. I guess we don't have to be correct everytime ?

Comment: dw - countered it :p. People should only down vote poor answers (usually one liners with no explanation), and this certainly is not. In addition, partial answers are acceptable to post as they may be helpful for other solvers - puzzles can often take more than one person to solve here.

Comment: Thanks @QuestionAsker for nullifying the down vote and the explanation

Comment: Nice try (and upvoted) but that's not it, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Alternate solution

> A nerdy guy in a movie

You like to have a drink after you kiss me

> More than likely because following the movie cliche it will be a really disgusting / awkward kiss

And if you've got the stomach for it, you can eat me

> Cannibalism was never ruled out (a horror movie nerd in this case)

When I am last, I am not least

> The nerdy guy always finishes last initially, it happens every movie, but they're typically a really intelligent and nice guy, so by no way are they the "least"

I'm said to overpower beasts

> Likely referring to all the movies like sorcerers apprentice where in the end it's the nerdy guy who defeats the monster / beast

And though I'm weak and thin and frail

> Yep, typical movie nerdy guy

Don't argue with my man - you'll fail

> Most likely referring to his one ultra-intelligent friend who is always right, in most movies, this is that "hacker friend"

**Not at all trying to be mean or stereotypical, just following the movie cliche!**

Comment: Sorry, interesting suggestion but you're quite far off course I'm afraid. The solution will be a lot more obviously correct than that once it's revealed.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, might have it! Could it be:

> A lemon in a margarita

You like to have a drink after you kiss me

> You suck (kiss) it as part of the drink

And if you've got the stomach for it, you can eat me

> Some people do eat the lemon, but it's not for everyone

When I am last, I am not least

> You suck it last, after taking a drink, and that makes it nice, whereas normally it is sour

I'm said to overpower beasts

> Anyone who drinks too much will quickly become intoxicated and overpowered.

And though I'm weak and thin and frail

> It's usually a thin slice, but still packs a punch

Don't argue with my man - you'll fail

> While drunk you're not going to win any arguments, and you shouldn't argue with someone who is drunk

Comment: Nope, still not it. But it's a creative solution, and is in some sense the closest one proposed so far.

Comment: Oh gosh! I feel silly trying multiple times but I really like this question :P! Before trying another answer, may I ask, is it something you could find in a bar (among other places [I don't mind if you'd rather not answer])?

Comment: I'd rather not answer. I have some hints I plan to add soon if no one makes any progress.

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly a Newfoundland Carp

```
You like to have a drink after you kiss me
```

> Kiss the Carp.

```
And if you've got the stomach for it, you can eat me
```

> Fish are edible.

```
When I am last, I am not least
```

> Carp swim upstream for breeding.  The "least" ones are the new born, not the last to swim unstream.

```
I'm said to overpower beasts
```

> A good catch can make a fisher swoon, and is not mankind the real beast?

```
And though I'm weak and thin and frail
```

> The riddle is being told by a shark.

```
Don't argue with my man - you'll fail
```

> You cannot argue with a Newfoundlander: to argue, you'd have to understand them.

```
Once more, who am I - can you guess?
```

> After kissing the carp *once more*, you are unlikely to be in a shape to guess.  I mean, how drunk do you have to be to do it twice?

```
Let's have a poll, it's only fair
```

> A reference to the July 22, 1948 referendum, which was both close and viewed as unfair.

```
In fact, I'm well within your grasp
Just when you feel close to despair
```

> A slogan used by Tourism Newfoundland.